# webview, download file on finish prepared document

Tags: android, webview

I'm using webview android.
I want to do basically is to download a file, when the server offers it to me.
Whatever happens, that until just the last post, "in a browser" does not give you the option to save the file.
Therefore, when I try to save the file in android, I never get save.

[image]

As you can see, it does not end until the last post, the browser does not have the file. It seems a method asynchronous

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
  {
   public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
   {
    //for downloading directly through download manager
    Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(request);
   }
  });
```

And these code, but can't open in browser because have Get and Post request to download PDF.

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

I can not think of other ways